# C++ opencv get cv::Point from index

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to extract data from a cv::Mat via the index of a pixel. This works fine for the colur e.g. cv::Vec3b, however when attempting to get the point information, it crashes stating:

> Error: Assertion failed (elemSize() == sizeof(_Tp)) in cv::Mat::at,

Here is the code I'm using:

```
cv::Mat src = imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
int max_index = src.size().area() // gives total amount of pixels (i.e. max index)
std::cout << src.at<cv::Vec3b>(max_index -1) << std::endl; // gives me colour of final pixel
std::cout << src.at<cv::Point>(max_index -1) << std::endl; // ERROR should give point of final pixel but crashes
```

How can I fix this so that I can get the Point at a specific pixel index?

Comment: what makes you think that `at` should return a point?
Your `src` is an image, it contains color values.

Comment: @Raildex I see. Well is there any supported way to get the Point via a index without manually doing the math?

Comment: What you want to do is something like: src.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(max_index -1, 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't, using `Mat::at()`. (it is meant to retrieve the pixel *content*, not the position)

the bottom-right point would be either:

```
Point(src.cols-1, src.rows-1);
```

or in your calculation:

```
Point((max_index-1)%src.cols, (max_index-1)/src.cols);
```

(imo, the whole idea of using `max_index`is somewhat impractical ...)

Comment: Should be the other way around? x=index%cols; y=index/cols; isnt it?

Comment: indeed, thanks for the correction, @Micka